# Can QT Quick use a png image sheet as a font?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have 2 separate PNG images that contains many font cells and need to be rendered together as a font where any character could be from a cell in one of the two png images. Can this be done in any way in Qt Quick?

Comment: Everything is possible, but you need to implement this functionality yourself.

Comment: @user1095108 well yes that's general programming theory, if that was the answer I was looking for I never would have even bothered to ask this question anywhere. But I'm obviously looking for something more concrete. As a revision to my question, what are some implementation ideas other Qt developers might have on tackling this problem?

Comment: Hehe, try to find a library for bitmap font rendering and then port that over to Qt. Your question is too generic, that's why I gave a generic answer. What do you mean, if I can render a bitmap font in Qt Quick? Do you need a BitmapText item? I'd use a QQuickItem approach and render using the QPainter subsystem, but we don't know what you need.

Comment: @user1095108 That's true, I'm still learning Qt but would it be easier to insert many individual sprite sheet animations and just not have it animate and give it a custom size and offset? Trying to leverage existing functionality rather than a full-on custom made solution. Wouldn't this come off as a typed font per-se and be much easier?

Comment: You need to rephrase your question, Qt and Qt Quick are not the same. What do you want to accomplish, there are no sprite sheets in either. If you persist in your Qt quest you'll see, you'll have to implement a lot of your own stuff.

Comment: @user1095108 https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-sprite.html - I guess this is what I'm talking about then. I'm referring to Qt Quick. Ultimately theres a desktop app I've made in Electron that I'm looking to port to something easier and more manageable. Qt Quick was a big candidate because I've used Qt a few times in the past and really liked it.